# Regex that do not match a line if any string from a list is present

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am writing a classification app for engineering data and I am faced with this tricky problem.  I have a (huge) list of piping components, and I need to classify them. What I have is something like this:

```
...
FLANGE NECK
FLANGE BLIND
STUB END ... with FLANGE
FLANGE ... foo
FLANGE
...
```

When I have only FLANGE, I want to match it to the "SIMPLE FLANGE" category. All the other entries need to be matched to specific kind of flange.

I have found that `FLANGE((?!NECK).)*$` will not match "FLANGE NECK" but will match "FLANGE BLIND", and I don't want that.

So, I figured that what would solve my problem is something like this:

`/FLANGE(*NOT NECK*)(*NOT BLIND*)(*NOT WITH STUB*).../`

Any thoughts on how to handle it?

PS: I'm doing the regex thing in Excel's VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the alternation operator, `|`.

```
/FLANGE (?!NECK|BLIND|STUB)/
```